# Как в eclipse в java-проект добавить файл .class?

Tags: java, eclipse

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться! Как в eclipse в java-проект добавить файл .class? Если делаю через 'Add Class Folder...', то в проект добавляется именно папка с классам. А по скольку это папка, а не пакет, то потом к подключенному классу никак не могу обратиться из программы.

Comment: не совсем уверен что вам вообще надо додавать `.class` в ваш проект, опишите для чего вам нужно это?

Comment: У меня есть java-проект, экспортированный из одной программы. Там есть .jar файлы и файл .class. Мне нужно этот проект собрать и запустить (делаю это в eclipse). Jar-файлы я подключила, а файл .class подключить не получается.

Comment: проект должен работать без `.class` а только с `.jar`, у вас возникает ошибка при компиляции?

Comment: У меня есть файл AS.class. В проекте есть создание объекта типа AS: ascode = new AS(fLib); Поскольку я не могу добавить в проект файл AS.clas, то создание объекта класса AS приводит к ошибке.

Comment: странно все это, что то здесь не так, но если только один файл, то вы можете создать свой класс `AS` и в него вставить код с `AS.class`